# Read and search text file in Python?

Tags: python

I need to write a Python script that reads a flat text file, searches for a string, and rewrites into a new text file.

I have this (example) script:

```
import re
read = open("file.txt", "r")
data = file.read()
print data
newfile = open("newfile.txt", "w")
for line in read:
  if re.match("(.*)dst="+str_var"(.*)", line):
    print newfile, line,
file.close()
```

Is there an easier or more correct way? (I know pretty much nothing about Python. This code is derived from what I've found in tutorials, google, etc.)

Thanks!

Comment: Does it work? If not, what exactly does/doesn't it do?

Comment: I haven't run it yet - this is only part of a much larger script that's not complete.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Well then you're not ready for a question here. Test the pieces independently before assembling them otherwise you'll end up with undebuggable monsters. If one of the pieces doesn't work and you can't figure out why, post here with the exact error and what you tried to fix it.

Comment: should it be `newfile = open("newfile.txt", "w")`?

Comment: You have a few issues. Check out some docs [7.2.1](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html)

Comment: Yes Josh (edited) and thanks MakeCents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may do the trick

```
read_file = open("file.txt", "r")
data = read_file.read()
read_file.close()
file_content = re.sub("\d+", "", data)
word = your_word
if word in file_content:
   newfile = open("newfile.txt", "w")
   print >> newfile, word
   newfile.close()
```